# PC shut off and will not start

Tags: hard-drive, shutdown

I have a PC that has been running without any problems for more than a year. Last night, I was playing Wasteland 2, when the computer just shut off. There was no power surge that I am aware of--nothing else in the house flickered or anything.

Now, when I turn it on, the HDD spins up, and the LED under the front-of-case power button lights up, but literally nothing else happens. None of the fans spin up, no POST beeps, nothing. The front power button doesn't even work--I have to use the switch on the back.

It has been turned off for approximately 21 hours, so heat is not likely the problem. Now I'm at a loss... any ideas?

**EDIT**

After some messing around, I determined that the PC boots up and runs fine if I remove the video board and use only the onboard graphics. I'm going to pick up a multimeter this evening and test the PSU. If that is fine, I guess it is the video card (which thankfully, carries a two year warranty).

Also, there was no POST beep because I had them turned off in the BIOS. :-)

**EDIT 2**

I picked up a cheap multimeter, and followed the instructions from a variety of places to test the PSU. I didn't test it under load/while it was turned on, but did test the 12V, the 5V and the 3.3V rails, and all are very close to the expected numbers (12.18, 5.05 and I'm not sure how important it is to test it under load--any opinions?

**EDIT 3**

Bit the bullet and tested it under load. Now it seems to be working fine--no issues. I guess I'll just keep an eye on it. I've still got 10 months on my video card warranty...

Comment: Since fans are not spinning it sounds like a mainboard issue. It could of course be a PSU issue but since the 12V for the HD works its less likely. Heat should not be an issue after being turned off for a while, the heat could have been an issue while playing if the hardware did not throttle down properly.

Comment: Does the HDD spin down or does stay on after?

Comment: I would start by disconnecting everything not needed for the machine to start up. I had a similar problem recently, and it was a failed USB headset!

Comment: PSU might be operating improperly (but still enough to supply some power to some locations).  Otherwise, problem is most likely with Mobo (a.k.a. motherboard).  Other equipment is unlikely to affect multiple fans in a standard PC (although if you have once of those fancy pieces of hardware that controls fan speed of multiple fans, that could do it).  If you have time, and no budget (to buy replacement parts), consider swapping parts, like placing PSU in another system and seeing if it works better there.  (Note that some PSUs might not have the right connectors for some mobo's.)

Comment: If you try all of the recommendations here and can't solve it, you might want to get a diagnostic card similar to this: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000234U3I?ref_=cm_cr_pr_product_top (there are a number of different ones ranging from a few dollars to about $15 on Amazon).  It will give you feedback on what's happening when it tries to power up.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like a motherboard issue. The power unit seems to work. You can test that with a multimeter pretty easily. If you get a multimeter even a basic one should do so do not spend money on it if you know you won't use it afterwards. Though it is always a good idea to have a somewhat decent multimeter in the house take my advice.

I would try to get onto the BIOS but it seems from how you describe it this won't be possible either. So try taking the mobo out and disconnect all connectable parts. Clean everything from dust. Perhaps add some new cooling paste onto your CPU (chip). Make sure, if you have, to also remove any batteries there might be on the mobo, and put them back in place later on.

Now reconnect everything and see if that help. If this did not work try and see if you can get a new mobo somewhere or have it checked by a service.

I hope it is just dust maybe or a bit of a wonky-wibbly-wobbly connection and after pluggin it things should be fine. Fingers crossed.

Last thing comes to mind could also be the video card, but if there is no beep there is no beep so my tip is it is the mobo unfortunately. Had this happen to me and had to replace it. But you could be in luck and the cleaning will help. Worth a shot for sure. All the best with it! Good luck!!